# JBoss EAP 6.2: "This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests."

Tags: jboss, proxy, server, war

I am new to JBoss and currently have deployed a WAR file in JBoss EAP 6.2 at C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\deployments, and whenever I'm Accessing the JBoss home from 127.0.0.1:8080, a page with "This is a proxy server. Does not respond to non-proxy requests." appears everytime. what could be the issue and how can it be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue with not setting all HTTP headers.
I had similar problem while working with socket programming and could resolve issue by including appropriate headers